# how to download a file with php and angular

Tags: php, angular, typescript

I already uploaded a file and saved the path into my database, but the problem now is that I can't download it. I have already tested the PHP code and it works, but when I try to download it from the Angular side it doesn't. Instead I get this error in the console:

```
httpErrorResponse error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token p in JSON at position 0
  at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
  at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (localhost:4200/vendor.js:164415:51)
  at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (localhost:4200/polyfills.js:9799:31)
  .........
```

ANGULAR SERVICE:

```js
public getjointes(filepath:string){
  const params = new HttpParams()
    .set('filepath', filepath);
  return this.http.get(url+'/download.php', {params: params });
}
```

TYPESCRIPT / function

```js
telecharger(path:string) {
    console.log(path);
    this.stream.getjointes(path).subscribe(response => {
        console.log(response);
    });
}
```

PHP CODE:

```php
$rest = $_GET['filepath'] ;

echo($rest);
$filepath = 'upload/' . $rest;

if (file_exists($filepath)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($filepath));
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize('upload/' . $rest));
    readfile('upload/' . $rest);
    header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Disposition");   
}
else{
    echo ('noo');
}
```

Comment: If you output anything (e.g. `echo($rest);`) then subsequent calls to `header()` are ignored. Ensure any calls to `header()` are made before *any* output.

Comment: For future questions, please be sure to fully describe the problem you're having (not just "it doesn't work") and include appropriate error messages from your server logs. After checking your search engine of choice for solutions to those error messages of course.

Comment: echo($rest) =>output: filename

Comment: and in the console , it gives me a httpErrorResponse  "error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token p in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:164415:51) at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:9799:31) .........

Comment: window.open(‘download.php’)..?

Comment: response header:                                                                                        Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000
Content-Description: File Transfer
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=ppp-20210516123801.txt
Expires: 0
Cache-Control: must-revalidate

Comment: @MikeOne what do you mean

Answer (score 1):

Ok I'm going to assume the `echo` statements in your PHP are just for testing, based on the error messages you included in comments.

I think the problem you're having is that Angular assumes the response will be JSON and attempts to parse it. To [avoid this behaviour](https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-non-json-data), you can set the `responseType` parameter to "text" or "blob" (for binary data) in your code:

```js
public getjointes(filepath:string) {
    const params = new HttpParams()
      .set('filepath', filepath);
    return this.http.get(url+'/download.php', {params: params, responseType: "text"});
}
```

Note that any output before a call to `header()` will result in the HTTP header **not** getting set. Your PHP code calls `header()` after `readfile()`. That header will be ignored. In addition, if a file is not found you should say so with a proper 404 header. This way your client-side code can respond properly to failures. Your PHP should look like this:

```php
$rest = $_GET['filepath'];
$filepath = 'upload/' . $rest;

if (file_exists($filepath) && is_readable($filepath)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($filepath));
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize('upload/' . $rest));
    header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Disposition");   
    readfile('upload/' . $rest);
} else {
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
}
```

Comment: ok , now it just show me the the contents of the file in the console @miken32

Comment: Yes, you've subscribed to the response in your TypeScript and told it to do that: `console.log(response);`

Comment: yeah i know but i still don't understand how i can download it @miken32

Comment: i know that my question is a little bit stupid but i'm beginner @miken32

Comment: Your Javascript code is downloading it. Do you want the end user to download it instead? Then you shouldn't be doing any of this. Just put a link like `<a href="download.php?filepath=whatever">Download</a>`